# SSHtunnelForwarder to Linux Box, then connect to Postgres RDS (AWS)

Tags: postgresql, aws, python, ssh, amazon-rds-aurora

I'm trying to write a python script to update DDL in a Aurora RDS (postgres) on AWS.  In Order to do this, I need to SSHTunnel to a linux box that sits at the edge of the VPC, then do another jump to the RDS server.  When I am connecting to the RDS via psql client on the Linux Box, I'm able to connect fine.  But, when trying to sshtunnel via SSHTunnelForwarder in python, I get an error saying: `sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway`

Here is my code:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (LinuxBoxHost,22),
    ssh_username='ubuntu',
    ssh_pkey="/path/to/.pem file",
    remote_bind_address=(RDSHostName,5432)) as server:

    server.start()
    print(server.local_bind_port)
```

I can't even test my connection to the RDS DB because I can't event hit the Linux Box via SSH.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've looked at various examples online, and it seems like the parameters I'm inputting seem accurate.

I'm wondering if I am just missing something conceptual here? Is this even possible? Perhaps the way I'm imagining our network infrastructure is not correct, but I've talked to our IT person, and it seems like I have the right idea. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: "I can't event hit the Linux Box via SSH" - that doesn't sound like a database related issue so almost certainly off topic here. You would be much better off asking on serverfault.com. Things to add when you ask over there: can you connect to that host via SSH without asking for tunnels? Can you tunnel to anything else just not the DB? Can you connect to other SSH hosts? Also if you have sufficient access to the SSH server, see if there are any logs for the connection attempt that might reveal if the issue is an authentication problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's fair, I will try to ask over there, thank you!